# Connecting Bing map in VB using web browser

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, bing-maps

I have written this code which allows the user to click my map button which then takes them to Bing maps the only problem is originally when I was using google maps instead the address would automatically populate the search field and complete search for me, I recently have had to switch to bing maps because Google maps would freeze and would tell me its unsupported. I would just like to know what I have to add in addition to my code to allow bing to automatically search with the information it has gather from my fields that it is linked to.

```
Private Sub BTNMap_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNMap.Click
    Form2.Show()

    ' Search google maps for the exchange

    Dim Postcode As String = PostcodeTextBox.Text
    Dim Address As String = AddressTextBox.Text



    Try
        Dim queryAddress As New StringBuilder

        queryAddress.Append("http://www.bing.com/maps/?")

        If PostcodeTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
            queryAddress.Append(Postcode + "," & "+")
        End If

        If AddressTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
            queryAddress.Append(Address + "," & "+")
        End If

        Form2.Internet.Navigate(queryAddress.ToString)


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve data")
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: VB6 doesn't have `try - except` so it isn't VB6. VB6 doesn't have `StringBuilder` (we have the `mid` statement - different to the `mid` function).

Answer (score 0):

Several options - you can read the documentation on the [Bing API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx), you can read the documentation on the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest), or you can just take a look at a [Google Maps search URL](https://www.google.com/maps/place/1600+Amphitheatre+Pkwy+94043) and take it from there:

```
' Search google maps for the exchange

Dim Postcode As String = PostcodeTextBox.Text
Dim Address As String = AddressTextBox.Text

Try
    Dim queryAddress As New StringBuilder

    queryAddress.Append("https://www.google.com/maps/place/")
    If AddressTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
        queryAddress.Append(String.Join("+", Address.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), _ 
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)))
    End If

    If PostcodeTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
        queryAddress.Append("+" & PostcodeTextBox.Text)
    End If

    Form2.Internet.Navigate(queryAddress.ToString)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve data")
End Try
```